# Dynamically Create Views from parameters/variables SQL SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a table that contains just under a million rows. I'm building a form using SSIS that asks for user input and uses the values as parameters to build a view from source data. I'm having trouble getting SSIS to create the view from a variable.

The purpose of this 'tool' is to provide a dialogue that programmatically builds a view and later an update statement based upon parameters defined via a form that will execute an SSIS package. A number of the ppl on my team know 0 SQL. Therefore this circumvents any SQL knowledge. Creating an entirely standalone app is not ideal as it would require too much additional overhead on my side and would deviate from a number of our existing processes that currently use SSIS/SQL to achieve similar results.

With that here is what I've tried/trying.

I have an SSIS package that contains 'Execute SQL Task'

This task brings up a form with 5 inputs (variables)
var1,var2,var3,var4,var5.
some vars are strings others are doubles, ints etc... (they all vary)

You populate the fields and hit okay.
These variables are passed to an 'Execute Package Task'.
Inside this package (Package B)
the vars are used in an 'Execute SQL Task'.

This task is attempting to take the users input and create a view with a where clause containing 4 other variables.

example:

```
Create View ? AS Select col1,col2,col3,col4 WHERE
col1 = ?
AND col2 =?
AND col3 =?.........
```

First it appears that using ? in the create view is invalid.
The error being:

```
Error: 0x0 at Build_Query: Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.
Error: 0xC002F210 at Build_Query, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "CREATE VIEW ? as Select * from S_t_equip_template
..." failed with the following error: "The batch could not be analyzed because of compile errors.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established

 correctly.
Task failed: Build_Query
```

If I use the create view variable as an expression and remove the variables/paramerters for the where statements, I can create the view no problem.
However the where statements throw errors once I add them back in. I've tried evaluating these as an expression in the 'Execute SQL Task' but as these are of various types I get the error:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "
CREATE VIEW testing AS SELECT
P.label,P.uniq..." failed with the following error: "The metadata could not 
be determined because statement 'CREATE VIEW testingagain AS SELECT
P.label,P.uniqueid,C.label as Child_Label,C.uniqueid as Child_uni' does not 
support metadata discovery.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the 
query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, 
or connection not established correctly.
```

No idea what is going on. Any help would be appreciated

I've googled the error and found some info but the other use-cases are so different that it's difficult to understand the actual cause, or another work around.

AS requested (simplified example):
I've created a package variable (datatype string) called: View_Name

Execute SQL Task:

```
CREATE VIEW @[User::View_Name] AS SELECT
* from table1 
where col1 = 100;
```

Specifically it does not like that I use a variable here.
If I set the View name everything works until: I move on to my Where clauses that contain variables.

Create a variable called type (datatype int)

I map the variable/parameter in my sql task

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW tempTable AS SELECT
    * from table1 
    where col1 = ?;
```

This won't work, same error.

If i attempt to do the above via an expression or expressions I get the following error

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "CREATE VIEW test_45678 AS SELECT P.label,P.uniquei..." failed with the following error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@".". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Generally having to due with the variables cannot be evaluated this way. I'm guessing I'd need to evaluate each piece individually and build the expression piece by piece. That's fine but very inefficient and not maintainable.

Comment: Can you show the step details?

Comment: @artm post updated with example

Comment: SSIS is really not built for interactive use, and dynamic SQL is usually a last resort in a database. Why are you doing all this? There's probably a better way. With regards to your error: Have you tried creating an expression inside a variable that contains the full `CREATE VIEW` definition, then evaluate it, then run it in SSMS to confirm it works, then run a SQL Task using 'SQL From Variable'

Comment: But really I'm curious why you are doing this. Are you trying to solve a performance issue through views? it won't make a difference. It's underlying indexes that make a difference

Comment: Trying to create a view with a hard coded name gives `The CREATE VIEW SQL construct or statement is not supported.` so...

Comment: What is the actual view definition when you get this error? In the sample posted above, the view definition is invalid, but I guess the error messages truncates it. Can you post the physical view definition that you aree using to get this error

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid   I've attempted using expressions but no luck thus far. I can get it to work for the create View piece, but the Where clauses throw the same errors and the expressions don't appear to evaluate fully. Reason being these are types ranging from decimals to strings etc. I'm stuck with SSIS and SQL to achieve this goal.

Comment: Why would you want a user to be able to create a bunch of views in a DB? sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't understand the things you've tried and the errors you get based on your explanation. Also I don't understand what you're actually trying to do. Why does a user need to create views in a database via SSIS? If you could edit your explanation to explain the cases you've tried and what the results are (an actual error message) I might be able to help. But overall whatever you're trying to do really makes no sense

Comment: FYI the only way you will be able to do this is pre-create the entire thing inside an SSIS variable, then execute that variable. This has the added benefit that you can scrape out the final SQL and test it in SSMS.  Check this for an example of what I'm talking about http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2007/07/22/ssis-design-pattern-dynamic-sql.aspx You generate the entire SQL statement in one string  However rather than popping it up in a script task, you execute it in an execute SQL task

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thank you Nick that did help me find my problem. My evaluation of the expressions was way off. I had to cast all of my variables to strings for them to evaluate as intended and there were other syntax issues with my expression as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had some fundamental misunderstanding in my attempt to evaluate my expressions. Specifically syntax issues and having to cast each variable to a string.
My SQLstatement variable

```
ON C.pid = P.ID 
where
C.width >="+(DT_WSTR, 8)@[User::Width] +"-"+ (DT_WSTR, 8)@[User::Range]+........
```

The final expression looks like so:

```
"Create View "+@[User::View_Name] + " AS SELECT " + @[User::SQLStatement]
```